# How to subset a data.frame according to the values of last two rows?

Tags: r

###the original data

```
df1 <- data.frame(a=c(2,2,5,5,7), b=c(1,5,4,7,6))
df2 <- data.frame(a=c(2,2,5,5,7,7), b=c(1,5,4,7,6,3))
```

when the a column value of the last two rows are not equal (here the 4th row is not equal to the 5th row, namely, 5!=7), I want to subset the last row only.

#input

```
 > df1
      a b
    1 2 1
    2 2 5
    3 5 4
    4 5 7
    5 7 6
```

#output

```
> df1
  a b
1 7 6
```

when the a column value of the last two rows are equal (here 5th row is equal to the 6th row, namely, 7=7,  I want to subset the last two rows

#input

```
> df2
  a b
1 2 1
2 2 5
3 5 4
4 5 7
5 7 6
6 7 3
```

#output

```
> df2
  a b
1 7 6
2 7 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it this way

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  filter(a == last(a))

  a b
5 7 6

  a b
5 7 6
6 7 3
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write a function to check last two row values for `a` column :

```
return_rows <- function(data) {
  n <- nrow(data)
  if(data$a[n] == data$a[n - 1])
      tail(data, 2)
  else tail(data, 1)
}

return_rows(df1)
#  a b
#5 7 6

return_rows(df2)
#  a b
#5 7 6
#6 7 3
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `subset` from `base R`

```
subset(df1, a == a[length(a)])
```